# Series of numbers with minimized risk of collision

Tags: math, hash, computer-science

I want to generate some numbers, which should attempt to share as few common bit patterns as possible, such that collisions happen at minimal amount. Until now its "simple" hashing with a given amount of output bits. However, there is another 'constraint'. I want to minimize the risk that, if you take one number and change it by toggling a small amount of bits, you end up with another number you've just generated. Note: I don't want it to be impossible or something, I want to minimize the risk!

How to calculate the probability for a list with `n` numbers, where each number has `m` bits? And, of course, what would be a suitable method to generate those numbers? Any good articles about this?

Comment: Please look up "Hamming distance".

Comment: @joop yes, I want to maximize the *chance* of the hamming distance between each node being as high as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question precisely, you need to say what exactly you mean by "collision", and what you mean by "generate". If you just want the strings to be far apart from each other in hamming distance, you could hope to make an optimal, deterministic set of such strings. It is true that random strings will have this property with high probability, so you could use random strings instead.

When you say

> Note: I don't want it to be impossible or something, I want to minimize the risk!

this sounds like an XY problem. If some outcome is the "bad thing" then why do you want it to be possible, but just low probability? Shouldn't you want it not to happen at all?

In short I think you should look up the term "error correcting code". The codewords of any good error correcting code, with any parameters that you feel like, will have the minimal risk of collision in the presence of random noise, for that number of code words of that length, and they can typically be generated very easily using matrix multiplication.

Comment: What kind of formular is out there to actually determine wether a random generation has a low enough risk?
Oh and also, when two numbers I've generated are equal I call it a collision. The reason why I want to just minimize the risk and not to kill it: You may choose how many numbers you want to generate and this limit may exceed a certain value for certain bit sizes, such that a collision or similar looking keys are unavoidable.

Comment: "What kind of formular is out there" I mean, it's not like there's going to be some famous person's name and a wikipedia page about this formula, whatever exactly it is you want. It sounds like it's about a homework-level difficulty to construct it. You might want to look at the estimates related to the "birthday paradox" and other estimates related to error correcting codes, or "probabilistic combinatorics" in general.

Comment: Thats my main issue, it doesnt relate to Code Theory, or at least in that way, that I should not directly use it. Thus I cannot say that I generate all and if some checksum is wrong I shouldnt use that number for whatever. Thanks for your directions